# Yii2 pretty url works on hosting but not locally

Tags: php, image, yii

I am using a controller action in Yii2 in order to serve images (possibly after resizing if required) and to keep them hidden from non site members.

The action is **actionImage($id)** in the site controller.
The images are stored under a base directory called **images** that may resides out of the DOCUMENT_ROOT. 
The action takes a parameter which is the relative path to the image under the **images** folder e.g. articles/myimage.jpeg
I have the following config:

```
  'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'enableStrictParsing' => false,
            'rules' => [
               ...
               'site/image/<id:^(\w+/){1}(\w+/){0,9}\w+\.\w+$ >' => 'site/image',
                ...
               ,
            ],
```

With this I expect /site/image/articles/pasajes036.jpg to serve the articles/pasajes.jpg under images.

I also tried `<id:.+>` in the rule but the result is the same i.e:

- It works fine when run by a remote server.
- It doesn't work when run by the yii embeded server (php yii serve) 
  Response is

> The requested resource /site/image/articles/pasajes036.jpg was not
>   found on this server.
>    - The image is correctly served when called with

```
http://localhost:8080/site/image?id=articles/pasajes036.jpg
```

- Other pretty url work on both servers (local and remote)
- It doesn't work locally even if the images folder is placed under the DOCUMENT_ROOT

Thank you for help.

Comment: What are the your server and local OS's and web server?

Comment: In fact it is only the dot that causes trouble.

Comment: I test it with very simple patterns like \w+\.\w+ . It works only on remote server.

Comment: I forgot to answer. Apache for remote, yii embeded for local

Answer (score 0):

You need to set rewriting rules for the server for pretty URLs to work.

In case of Apache it's easy - you can just use mod_rewrite module.

For built-in PHP server it's more complicated but still possible. There is example at [gonzalo123.com](https://gonzalo123.com/2012/10/15/how-to-rewrite-urls-with-php-5-4s-built-in-web-server/):

> But, does it work with the built-in web server? The answer is yes, but with another syntax. We only need to create one router file and start our server with this router:

```
<?php
// www/routing.php
if (preg_match('/\.(?:png|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/', $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"])) {
    return false;
} else {
    include __DIR__ . '/index.php';
}
```

> And now we start the server with:

```
php -S localhost:8888 www/routing.php
```

So you just need to create routing PHP script that will handle rewriting.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I am not sure I understand well as it seems to be the opposite of what I expect. Using what you suggest with the yii embedded server leads to url like localhost:8080/routing.php/<controller name>/filename.jpeg to be refused. But when writting if (preg_match ('/\.(?:)$/', …  url rule in config/web.php works fine with all file extensions.

Comment: it even works with routing.php only containing the include line

Comment: This is just the example, you have to modify it for your needs.